# How would I match names to memberships in organizations using HashMaps in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset, sorting

So here is my predicament. I have no idea where to start with this. Lets say i'm given a list of people that are members of multiple organizations like the following:

```
John NAACP PETA NRA
Bill NRA WHO
Nancy NAACP NRA WHO
Jim PETA WHO
```

But I want to take another file in that has a list of all the possible organizations and then output something like this (with the organizations in alphabetical order and the members also in alphabetical order, and no names next to an organization if nobody is in it):

```
NAACP John Nancy
NRA Bill John Nancy
PETA Jim John
WHO Bill Jim Nancy
YEO
```

I'm new to HashMaps and I have no idea how to go about doing this, so i'd appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Reading this post and subsequently looking at your post history suggests you are just using this site to have people do your homework for you.  Please don't do that.  Try and do the assignment yourself and actually learn something.  Learning something is more valuable than getting a good grade.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`.  Insert each organization name as a String key with an empty `ArrayList<String>`.  Then loop over the list of people => organizations, look up the organizations one by one, and insert the person's name in the `ArrayList` for that organization.

Comment: Was going to add code example, but a la @JustinL give it try for yourself!

Comment: I actually had no idea you could put an ArrayList in as a value for a HashMap, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution but it will work

To add people to the list you can use the following code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> storage = new 
LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>>();
if(!storage.containsKey("NRA")){
   storage.put("NRA", new ArrayList<String>());
}

storage.get("NRA").add("Bill");
storage.get("NRA").add("John Nancy");
```

To extract and print people you can use the following code:

```
for(Entry<String, List<String>> entry : storage.entrySet()){
    String line = entry.getKey(); //getting company name

    for(String name : entry.getValue()){  //extracting name from an array
         line += " ";
         line += name;
    }

    System.out.println(line);  //printing the result
}
```

I didn't check this code in IDE but except possible typos it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap for each organization, e.g., `HashMap<String,Boolean> memberOfNAACP = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();`. As you loop through the members and you find one who is a member of NAACP, run `memberOfNAACP.put("John",true)`. When you're done, dump out the contents of the hash with `memberOfNAACP.keySet()`. If you don't know all the organizations in advance, use an `ArrayList` of `HashMap`s, type `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Boolean>>`.